# ActiveRecord connection select from a postgresql function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am performing this query on my function:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM organic_reports('#{@date}');")`

The function is returning the following attributes:

`name(string), project_id(int), report_id(int), created_at(date), stats(int)`

How can I use ActiveRecord to query those results, like in a normal Rails model? Methods like (where, find etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `from` to define the source of the query, and then you can use the ActiveRecord query interface as you normally would.

```
Model.from("organic_reports('#{@date}')").where('...').group('...')
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, what is the `model` suppose to be?

Comment: `Model` is just a stand-in for whatever model you want to use for this purpose since I don't know anything about your app.  I could have used `FooBarBaz` instead...  `Model` is not already defined by Rails.

Comment: Yea, I thought that, but still it didn't work, when I was passing a param to my function, I was saying that it can't find the column, and when I wasn't sending any param in my function, it was saying that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: If you remove `where('...').group('...')` from above, it will generate a query identical to what you're currently using.  Would you mind posting the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define a model for the organic_reports table?

```
class OrganicReport < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now it is a Rails model which you can query normally:

```
OrganicReport.find_by(project_id: 1)
OrganicReport.where('name LIKE ?', "#{name}")
```

Comment: `organic_reports` is a table-valued function, not a table.  How does he call the function with this?